# Как вывести записи текущего выбранного месяца в связке с плагином js fullcalendar

Tags: wordpress

**Задача:** выводить список записей на страницу, в зависимости от выбранного месяца в плагине *[fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io)*. (делаю новостную страницу в связке с календарем)

Даты записей в postmeta имеют ключи `event_start` и `event_end`.
Тип записи `calendar_event`.

То есть, если в календаре сейчас выбран ноябрь, то нужно вывести все записи у которых `event_start` или `event_end` попадают в диапазон выбранного месяца.

В плагине по кнопкам можно листать вперед и назад месяц, а так же вернуться к текущему месяцу.

Я нашел такой способ ограниченного вывода записей, но зашел в тупик, как связать с fullcalendar *(в данном случае у меня корректно выводится ровно 2 записи, которые находятся в диапазоне с 8 по 12 ноября)*

```
<?php
    global $post;

    $myposts = get_posts([ 
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_type'   => 'calendar_event',
        'order'       => 'date'
    ]);

    if( $myposts ){
        foreach( $myposts as $post ){
            $date_start = (int)get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_start', true);
            $date_end = (int)get_post_meta($post->ID, 'event_end', true);
            if ($date_start >= 20231108 && $date_start <= 20231112) {
                setup_postdata( $post );
            
?>
    <div>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_field('event_start'); ?>
        <?php the_field('event_end'); ?>
        <?php the_field('event_url'); ?>
    </div>
<?php 
        } else {
                
        }     }
    } else {
        
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Я нашел, как получить текущие первый и последний день активного месячного окна (то есть там затрагивает прошлый месяц и, возможно, следующий, если он находится в отображаемом диапазоне). *В скриншоте ниже пример, я могу вывести в console.log текущий активный диапазон дат 30 октября и 10 декабря. Но опять же, это все на js, если бы я мог передать эти даты в цикл с выводом записей - уже ближе реализация задачи была бы, так как я вывожу посты через get_posts()*
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Даты получил следующим образом:

```
var view = calendar.view;
console.log(view.activeStart);
console.log(view.activeEnd);
```

И приходят в консоль в следующем виде:

```
[Log] Mon Oct 30 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время) (script.js, line 33)
[Log] Mon Dec 11 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время) (script.js, line 34)
```

Comment: Для вывода по датам в ВП существуют [шаблоны архивов](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2#.D0.9E.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B1.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B6.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B4.D0.B0.D1.82.D1.8B)

Comment: Я может быть пытаюсь связать не связываемое. Как бы вы реализовали календарь событий? js/jquery плагином/библиотекой или использовали бы календарь, написанный на php? Именно что бы записи работали в связке с календарем, который отображается в сайдбаре например. Какой месяц там выбран - записи того месяца и выводятся. Адекватных плагинов в WP бесплатных не нашел, решил искать альтернативу

Comment: Для стандартных записей есть родной виджет календаря. Но к "событиям" это не имеет никакого отношения. Для  "календаря событий" полно самых разных плагинов. Но судя по задаче они тебе не нужны - всё есть прямо из коробки.